# PHP: Linking an array value with a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that stores names of countries (keys) and age expectancy (values).

```
$countries = array(  
  'Costa Rica' => 78, 'Puerto Rico' => 78, 'Colombia' => 73, 
  'Nicaragua' => 73, 'El Salvador' => 72, 'Peru' => 71,
  'Argentina' => 75, 'Uruguay' => 76, 'Ecuador' => 75,
  'Mexico' => 76, 'Venezuela' => 73, 'Brasil' => 72,
);
```

An html form creates a new variable (`$country`) with a name that corresponds to one countries listed above.
For example: `"Costa Rica"`

How can I return a variable with the number (age expectancy) that matches the name of the country in the `$country` variable?
Take for example:

```
Costa Rica = 78
$ageExpectancy = 78;
```

Thanks, I hope to be concise.

Comment: The PHP manual is quite good. Learn about arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
$country = $_POST['country']; // assuming post method and form element named 'country'
$ageExpectancy = $countries[$country];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know I could actually call the same string with the variable itself.